# How do I switch my Wordpress URL correctly

Tags: wordpress, url

I would like to switch my testing website url from www.hello.com/testing to www.hello.com
After I changed the url the website display non-safety.
What should I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1: leave the wordpress files in /testing directory and just change the index file to achieve target.
Scenario 2: move all the wordpress files to root directory and replace all URLs inside your database to remove /testing

Solution for Scenario 1:
Copy index.php and .htaccess files to your root directory. Open this new index.php to edit and search for /testing and remove it. Go to Admin panel -> settings -> General and change Site URL and remove /testing from here also.

Solutionfor Scenario 2:
Go to Admin panel -> settings -> General and change Site URL and remove /testing. Then move all your files to new location and run interconnectit script ([available here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/))